How to pronounce 那邊?
那邊 is pronounced nabian. In the dictionary, 那 is only pronounced na. Yet sometimes it is pronounced nebian, which is easier to say in the mouth. So is nebian an official pronunciation or just informal? Why isn't this pronunciation listed in the dictionary? Thanks.

This dictionary entry of the 重編國語辭典修訂本 says the following for "nèi" :

指示詞。單數用法，指比較遠的人、事、物。為「那（ㄋㄚˋ）一」合音成ㄋㄞˋ，再轉成ㄋㄟˋ。如：「我很欣賞那個人。」

Basically, 那邊 (nèibian) = 那一邊 nàibian. The pronunciation evolved as follows : nàibian > naìbian > nèibian.

The link doesn't work.

Please use VPN if you are in China! The link is  connect to 'dict.revised.moe.EDU.TW' .  Had been blocked by GFW. @joehua

@James I got to a 重編國語辭典 page that said "首頁>辭典檢視「那:ㄋㄚˇ」 ID Miss!! [2930]".

@joehua I can connect to : https://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/dictView.jsp?ID=2930&q=1&word=%E9%82%A3#order3

釋　　義
㈠ ㄋㄚˋ....
㈡ ㄋㄟˋ ...

ㄋㄚˋ
ㄋㄟˋ
ㄋㄚˇ
ㄋㄟˇ
ㄋㄚ
ㄋㄨㄛˊ
(點各音查相關詞)
漢語拼音
nà
nèi
nǎ
něi
nā
nuó

"那" can be pronounced as - nà, nǎ (formal), nèi, and něi (dialect). Note the symbol above the letter, which indicates the tone of the word is pronounced; the tune changes the meaning and usage of the word.

"那邊" is pronounced as "nàbian" or "nèibian", when one means to say "that side".
It is pronounced as "nǎbian" or "něibian" when one means to ask "Which side?"

